# PHP Complexe Header with SoapClient()

Tags: php, soap

I need to send Soap requests, but the server needs complex authentification and I don't no how create this header...

Target Soap structure :

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:int="http://www.gmc.net/Phoenix/Integration">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pass</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
       <int:ListTicketsRequest>
           <int:Company>test</int:Company>
       </int:ListTicketsRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My Php code

```html
<?php
try
{
 $wsdl = "https://aaa.wsdl";
 $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1));

 $header_part = '
 <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
  <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
   <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pass</wsse:Password>
  </wsse:UsernameToken>
 </wsse:Security>
 ';
 $soap_var_header = new SoapVar( $header_part, XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null );
 $soap_header = new SoapHeader( 'http://your-target-service.com', 'wsse', $soap_var_header );
 $client->__setSoapHeaders($soap_header);

 $res = $client->ListTickets(array('Company' => 'test'));
}
catch (SoapFault $fault)
{
 echo "SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring}) \n \n";

 echo "====== REQUEST HEADERS =====" . PHP_EOL;
 var_dump($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
 echo "========= REQUEST ==========" . PHP_EOL;
 var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());

}
?>
```

My result

```html
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.gmc.net/Phoenix/Integration" xmlns:ns2="http://your-target-service.com">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
   <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pass</wsse:Password>
   </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
 </SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:ListTicketsRequest>
   <ns1:Company>test</ns1:Company>
  </ns1:ListTicketsRequest>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Problems, Function SoapHeader need in first $data here 'http://your-target-service.com' (for testing). But my strucure include in native xmlns:ns1

Maybe my all my code is wrong..
I need your help !!

Thanks :)